# $X \subset \mathbb{R}^m$. Let $\phi:x \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be bounded. $\phi$ is continuous $\iff$ its graph is closed.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, continuity

> $X \subset \mathbb{R}^m$. Let $\phi:x \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be bounded. Then $\phi$ is continuous $\iff$ its graph is closed.

I was asked to prove this, but I believe it's false.

Let $Gra(\phi) = \{(x, \phi(x))|x \in X\}$ the Graph of $\phi$.

Suppose X is not closed. Then exists $a \in \bar{X}-{X}$ (being $\bar{X}$ the closure of X).

Therefore exists $x_n \in X$ s.t. $x_n \to a$. The sequence $\phi(x_n)$ has a convergent subsequence $\phi(x_{k_n})$ since it's bounded. Let $\lim \phi(x_{k_n})=b$

Then $(a,b) \in \overline{Gra(\phi)}$  (the closure of $Gra(\phi)$) but $(a,b)\not \in Gra(\phi) \implies Gra(\phi)$ is not closed.

Is this correct?

Comment: perhaps you are asked to show that the graph is *relatively* closed, that is the graph is closed in the subspace topology of $X\times\mathbb R^n$, not necessarily in $\mathbb R^m\times\mathbb R^n$

Answer (score 1):

Of course, when $X$ itself is not closed in $\mathbb{R}^m$, the graph cannot be closed. We henceforth assume that $X$ is closed.

Let $\mathcal{C}(X)$ denote the set of convergent sequences $\mathbf{x}=(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset X$. For any such sequence we will denote its limit by $x$. Notice that $x\in X$ by the assumption that $X$ is closed.

On the one hand, we have:

\begin{align}
\phi \text{ is continuous}&\iff \phi \text{ is sequentially continuous}\\
&\iff \forall \mathbf{x}\in\mathcal{C}(X), \,\phi(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\phi(x_n)\tag{1}\end{align}

On the other, we have

\begin{align}
Gra(\phi) \text{ is closed}&\iff Gra(\phi) \text{ is sequentially closed}\\
&\iff \forall \text{ convergent } \big(x_n,\phi(x_n)\big),\, \lim_{n\to\infty}\big(x_n,\phi(x_n)\big) \in Gra(\phi)\tag{2}
\end{align}

It is clear that $(1)\implies (2)$.
Indeed, if $\big(x_n,\phi(x_n)\big)$ is convergent, then $\mathbf{x}=(x_n)$ is convergent and hence by $(1)$ so too is $\big(\phi(x_n)\big)$,
with $\lim_{n\to\infty}\phi(x_n)=\phi(x)$.
Hence,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\big(x_n,\phi(x_n)\big)=\big(x,\phi(x)\big),$$

which belongs to $Gra(\phi)$ by definition.

---

We will show that when $\phi$ is bounded, $(2)\implies(1)$, which conludes the proof.

Suppose $\phi$ is bounded and let $\mathbf{x}\in\mathcal{C}(X)$.
Since $\phi$ is bounded and $(x_n)$ is convergent (and hence bounded), we have that $\big(\phi(x_n)\big)$ is a bounded sequence.
By the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem, there is a convergent subsequence $\big(\phi(x_{n_k})\big)$ of $\big(\phi(x_n)\big)$.

Of course, $(x_{n_k})$ it itself convergent and converges to $x$, the same limit of $(x_n)$.
It follows that $\big(x_{n_k},\phi(x_{n_k})\big)$ is convergent, and by $(2)$ we have that $\lim_{k\to\infty}\big(x_{n_k},\phi(x_{n_k})\big)=\big(x,\phi(x)\big)$.
In particular, $\lim_{k\to\infty}\phi(x_{n_k})=\phi(x)$.

It then suffices to show that $\big(\phi(x_n)\big)$ is convergent;
in this case, its limit must coincide with that of $\big(x_{n_k},\phi(x_{n_k})\big)$, that is, must equal $\phi(x)$. We show this by contradiction.

Indeed, if that were not the case, then there would be some $\epsilon>0$ and a subsequence $(x_{m_k})$ of $(x_n)$ with $d\big(\phi(x_{m_k}),\phi(x)\big)\geq \epsilon$ for all $k$.
Now, $\big(\phi(x_{m_k})\big)$ is of course bounded, so by the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem it must have a convergent subsequence, say $\left(\phi\left(x_{m_{k_j}}\right)\right)$.
By construction, we have that $$y=\lim_{j\to\infty}\phi\left(x_{m_{k_j}}\right)\neq \phi(x)$$

But $\left(x_{m_{k_j}}\right)$ is a subsequence of $(x_n)$, and hence converges to $x$.
It follows that $$\lim_{j\to\infty}\left(x_{m_{k_j}},\phi\left(x_{m_{k_j}}\right)\right)=(x,y)$$
and hence does not belong to $Gra(\phi)$, in contradiction with $(2)$. $\square$.

---

> Notice that in the proof above we didn't actually need the hypothesis that $\phi$ be bounded, but rather that $\phi$ 'preserves boundedness', ie, $\phi$ takes bounded sets to bounded sets.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense: $Gra(\phi)\mbox{ is sequentially close}\iff (x,y)\in Gra(\phi)$ nor does this: $y=\phi(x)\iff \phi(x)=\lim\phi(x_n)$. Also you didn't use the assumption that $\phi$ is bounded and without it the statement is not true.

Comment: Yes it does; $(x,y)$ is the limit of $(x_n,y_n)$, that is $y=\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n$. We hence need $\phi(x)=y=\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\phi(x_n)$.

Comment: Remember a set $S$ is sequentially closed if for every convergent sequence $(x_n)\subset S$ its limit also lies in $S$.

Comment: Right, I get it now. I just didn't know that $(x,y)$ in "iffs" are the same as defined earlier. However it is still incorrect. Consider $f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$, $f(0)=0$. The graph is clearly $[0,\infty)\times [0,\infty)$ so it is closed. Yet $f$ is not continous. Note that $f$ is not bounded, but you didn't use that assumption anywhere. The problem is that you start from a convergent sequence in the graph. But instead you should've started with a convergence sequence in $X$ and show that $\phi$ maps it to a convergence sequence.

Comment: You are right, I will fix it.

Comment: So I guest that "$\phi(x)=\lim\phi(x_n)\iff\phi\mbox{ is sequentially continous }$" is not true, because $x_n$ was specially picked (such that $y_n=\phi(x_n)$ is convergent).

Comment: @freakish I've fixed it, added a lot of details. I think it's clear now where the bounded hypothesis on $\phi$ is used.

Answer (score -1):

This is wrong (for unbounded function). take $\phi : [0, \infty] \rightarrow R$ with $\phi(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ for all $x \in (0, \infty)$ and $\phi (0)=0$. its graph is closed but $\phi$ is not continuous!

EDIT: The above example is for **unbounded** function on limited domain (before editing the original question). If we assume function is bounded then the claim  is correct.

Proof: For Left to Right: the function $F(x) = (x, \phi(x))$  is continuous (now to show graph is closed in $X \times R^n$, use the sequential definition of continuity of $F$).
For Right to Left: similar to your argument, take $x_n \rightarrow x \in X$. want to show that $\phi(x_n) \rightarrow \phi(x),$ if actually $\phi(x_n) \nrightarrow \phi(x)$ then (since $\phi$  is bounded)  $\phi (x_n)$ has a convergent subsequence, say $\phi (x_{n_{k}}) \rightarrow y \neq \phi(x)$, i.e., $$(x_{n_{k}},  \phi (x_{n_{k}}) ) \rightarrow (x,y)\notin \text{Graph}.$$

Which is contradicting with Graph being Closed.

Comment: This function is not "limited", which I assume actually means bounded.

Comment: question is saying It is Limited !

Comment: Then what is limited? And why your function is limited?

Comment: I took it the function is limited on $X$, restricted on $X$ not whole space !

Comment: OK, otherwise it is correct

Comment: You mean bounded. And your function is not, $\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\phi(x)=\infty$.

Comment: No, I meant domain is not entire $R^n$, if we assume boundedness then it is correct

Comment: It doesn't really matter what the domain is. The only thing that matters is whether we consider the graph to be closed in $X\times\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{R}^m\times\mathbb{R}^n$. In the first case this is true for bounded functions. In the second case this is false if $X$ is not closed in $\mathbb{R}^m$ (as pointed out by the OP), no matter what $f$ is.

Comment: -1: and your function **is not bounded**. So it is not a counterexample to anything. Why would you even consider unbounded functions when OP clearly talks about bounded only? Also your proofs are not proofs at all. I don't find this kind of sketches useful.

Comment: I  myself am saying  regardless the assumption of boundedness the claim is not true! And my counterexample indeed works. OP didn't use the word  boundedness, you yourself know that !! Why are you asking a question that you know its answer!  We already communicated like in 6 comments above, I took "limited" as the limited domain not boundedness. See Edit-Archive of the original question. I have no idea why after 9 comments you still haven't gotten, my example was for the unclear word (the Limited)  in original question, before Edit !!! even yourself you pointed out to it in you answer.

Comment: He didn't use the word boundness but it is (almost) clear from the context. At least how would you otherwise explain picking a convergent subsequence of $\phi(x_n)$? Yes, I had my doubt but after reading the question one more time there was none.

Comment: So what ! you are complaining because the original question was clear to you but not to me! If it was that clear it would have been never edited by  @Carsten S . As it is clear from my solution and its history I wrote that short part As Edit, AFTER editing question by.  
 My both counterexample before editing of question, and  the sketch of proof after editing work. I just took limited as something else than boundedness.

Comment: No, I'm complaining that you don't read questions, you post invalid examples, don't bother editing your answer (after the mistake has been pointed out) and put "sketches" of proofs. BTW I don't know why you are taking this personally. Just fix those errors and we're done.

Comment: I added a little detail two last lines, (Which I think it wasn't necessary).
Sketch of proof is quite common and acceptable here, specially for easy problems. + I don't see any errors in my answer to fix them ! 
I didn't take that personally.

Answer (score -1):

> $\iff$ its graph is closed.

That's ambiguous. Closed in what space? To be precise, usually the graph is considered closed in $X\times\mathbb{R}^n$ (as opposed to $\mathbb{R}^m\times\mathbb{R}^n$ which you consider in your counterexample).

That's reasonable because your argument is correct if we consider whole $\mathbb{R}^m\times\mathbb{R}^n$. What you've shown is that if $X$ is not closed in $\mathbb{R}^m$ then **no graph can be closed** in $\mathbb{R}^m\times\mathbb{R}^n$ for bounded functions. IMO this makes $\mathbb{R}^m\times\mathbb{R}^n$ uninteresting (in this context).

> Then $(a,b)\in \overline{Gra(\phi)}$

That's were you are wrong (at least under the proper assumption that we are considering $X\times\mathbb{R}^n$ as the universe). That point doesn't even belong to $X\times\mathbb{R}^n$ (because $a\not\in X$) so how can it belong to some subset? Your domain is $X$, not $\mathbb{R}^m$. Remember that the graph is defined as a **subspace of domain times codomain** and so the closure is also considered in $X\times\mathbb{R}^n$.

---

So here's the real proof. First of all I assume that by "limited" you actually mean bounded.

If $\phi$ is bounded, then that means that the image of $\phi$ is bounded. Thus

$$\mbox{im}(\phi)\subseteq C\subset\mathbb{R}^n$$

where $C$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (e.g. some closed ball). Now define

$$\phi':X\to C$$
$$\phi'(x)=\phi(x)$$

Note that $\phi$ is continous if and only if $\phi'$ is. Also graphs of $\phi$ and $\phi'$ are equal as sets.

On the other hand $\phi'$ is continous if and only if its graph is closed in $X\times C$ by [the closed graph theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_graph_theorem) (which applies since $C$ is compact). But since $X\times C$ is a closed subset of $X\times\mathbb{R}^n$ then the graph of $\phi'$ is closed in $X\times C$ if and only if it is closed in $X\times\mathbb{R}^n$.

All in all the following statements are equivalent:

- $\phi$ is continous
- $\phi'$ is continous
- graph of $\phi'$ is closed in $X\times C$
- graph of $\phi'$ is closed in $X\times\mathbb{R}^n$
- graph of $\phi$ is closed in $X\times\mathbb{R}^n$

---

This can be generalized as follows:

> Let $X, Y$ be topological spaces with $Y$ Hausdorff. Assume that $f:X\to Y$ is a function such that $\overline{\mbox{im}(f)}$ is compact. Then $f$ is continous if and only if the graph of $f$ is closed in $X\times Y$.

Comment: Downvoter, care to comment?

Comment: I didn't vote your answer down (I didn't it read at all), but I think it is worth to be voted down! for following reasons:
1-  OP is asking to prove the closed graph theorem for very particular case $Euclidean$ space. What you did, is applying the closed graph theorem for this particular case! (which is correct but not reasonable) The proof in this case goes through a simple argument about sequences! which mentioned in my answer and it is indeed correct (while you vote it down. I don't care)

Comment: Secondly, you said "since $C$ is closed then $\phi'$ is continuous iff $\phi$ is " closedness of $C$ does not paly any role here !

Comment: @nonlinearthought You are right, the closedness of $C$ is not required, I've fixed that. Also I don't see anything unreasonable in using classical, well known theorem in the proof. At least my proof is not a sketch.

Comment: The unreasonable thing is that, a person is asking help for proof of a classical, well known theorem, then we apply that classical, well-known  theorem in our proof to get result. BTW, If I would have Edited my solution, your comments wouldn't make any sense for people, it is really immoral. We should point out our edit, when an argument or challenge accrues.